# Algorithm for positioning random elements on an infinite plane

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm where I can establish psuedorandom positions within a given viewport (top, left, width height) without having to store those positions. Say I have a viewport from (0, 0) to (100, 100). I would then find elements at (67, 25), (36, 42), and (1, 2). If I were to change that viewport to from (-50, -50) to (50, 50), I would still find (36, 42) and (1,2) but I would then also maybe find one at (-14, 7) and (-32, -20).  I don't know how I can make this clearer.

Comment: Is the window size fixed? Is the window location quantized?

Comment: No it could be anything. I'm not sure what you mean by quantized. Considering what that means in physics, I'm thinking not. I want to be able to create a system where there are an infinite number of elements "randomly" distributed on an infinite plane where I can find and render only those that exist within my specific window.

Comment: Just a warning: You cannot cover *infinite plane* using calculations with finite number of bits. In other words, this task requires the least significant bits still available even if you go very far with your window, e.g. 10^1000.

Comment: I know that. I am looking for a way to calculate them for a given window. I've thought of maybe using positions as a random seed from which to build a random model, but I have not fleshed this out yet. There is a way, I was just hoping that someone might have come up with an algorithm already and save me the mind job.

Comment: Maybe I could build up regions of the plane using a random number generated seeded with a given region's position. Then I would have "infinite" finite regions. I'm not sure what to do when the window overlaps regions though. I guess I would have to build up all overlapped regions. I would rather find something that is more linear.

Comment: Chunking using region coordinates as a seed is a good approach, but is tricky to get truly uniform distribution, e.g. one where it's possible to get hundreds of points in one chunk, and zero in another.

Comment: @MooseBoys The first random number obtained for the chunk can be used for the number of points in that region. Different variants are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example working on integers. It could be modified to floats, too.

```
import random

STEP = 10  # size of square with random points
COUNT = 6  # number of random points in the square

def get_points(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    points = []
    sx = (x1 // STEP) * STEP
    sy = (y1 // STEP) * STEP
    for bx in range(sx, x2, STEP):
        for by in range(sy, y2, STEP):
            random.seed(bx + by)
            for i in range(COUNT):
                px = bx + random.randrange(STEP)
                py = by + random.randrange(STEP)
                if x1 <= px < x2 and y1 <= py < y2:
                    points.append((px, py))
    return points

print get_points(0, 0, 10, 10)
print get_points(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

The whole plane is covered with squares containing random points depending on the square location.

You find the location of the bottom-left square (`sx`, `sy`), then you calculate locations of all squares that are needed for the selected window (`bx`, `by`). You initialize the random number generator and then generate all necessary points in the square (`px`, `py`). But only points that are inside the window are actually considered.

Just for inspiration.

Comment: Nice.  To get well-distributed results, I think you'd want to generate the `COUNT` used for each square from a Poisson distribution with appropriate mean.  (Though a binomial would be more appropriate in the discrete case.)

Comment: That's cool and it can be extended into higher dimensions which I was also looking for (not part of this question). I think this might work.

Comment: @Jordan I confirm. You can use the same approach also for points in spaces with more dimensions.